# How to run blender 2.77 on a virtual network render machine with no Opengl support on windows?

Tags: rendering, opengl, network

I have a server that runs multiple instances of virtual machines and is running windows 10... there is a cinema 4d farm clients running there...and I need to run blender 2.77 slave mode ...but the problem is that blender 2.77 is not starting due to no video hardware acceleration on the virtual machine... Is there a way to
run blender skipping the video HW check?

Comment: I believe (forgive me if I am wrong), that you can launch blender in console mode with -b. See here for the full list of arguments: https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line.html THis should enable you to render things (apparently with the CPU).

Comment: Then again, tweaking the VM would seem the best way to solve it for good. Can that be done? At least in Linuxland it seems possible to run Blender without 3D acceleration (~ 7-10 years old physical box).

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer I managed to find a way to start the master and slave in comand line.no GUI. you configure blender with GUI interface to enable network render addon and save the userpref.blend file from  "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.77\config" and copy to all virtual machines you need...then in blender you save a file with a scene set to network render and master running with the name master.blend...do the same but in slave mode ...you will have a slave.blend file ...then move the 2 files to blender directory and run blender -b master.blend -a

Comment: blender -b slave.blend -a...and they will connect automaticaly...you can use blender 2.76b GUI to configure files inside the virtual machine is warning you about no hardware acceleration but blender is running fine...then use the files with blender 2.77 ... sorry about the bad english! :(